# Filling Web Form Text Box value In EO Web Browser

Tags: javascript, vb.net, dom

I am using this EO Web Browser from http://www.essentialobjects.com/ 
I want to fill the a webform textbox value Which is this.

For the source value It is my textboxt1 in my .net application Form1 
So I Want to fill the webform Textbox value with my Form1 Textbox1

I look upon their support form i found this but Unable to Put The .value = textbox1.text because its all in double quotes like this

For your understanding The Webview1 Is A Control Which Is Like To Regular
VB.net IE Web Browser control in visual studio But Use Chrome 49 As Its web engine

Webview.evalscript means Execeuting Javascript Code In Webview DOM Window

Now Return to real Question the Code they give is :

//Set textbox "user_name"'s value to "test"

```
webView1.EvalScript("document.getElementByid('user_name').value = 'test';")
```

So How Do I Manage to get something like this 
Dim txtboxval as string = textbox1.text
webView1.EvalScript("document.getElementByid('Email').value = 'txtboxval';")
Please Clarify This Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Dim scriptText As String = "document.getElementByid('user_name').value = '" & textbox1.text & "';"
webView1.EvalScript(scriptText)
```

I have not tested it but it seems like it should work.  I am creating a string apart from the EvalScript command, including your text box value, and then utilizing that concatenated string from within the EvalScript command.

Comment: Thanks for Answer I solved it a way similar to yours before i check this Answer page i do it like this :  WebView1.EvalScript("document.getElementById('Email').value=""" + TextBox4.Text + """;")